# Validate uploaded file is excel spreadsheet in C# restful webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, validation

I am attempting to validate that a file that is being uploaded via multipart form data is in fact an excel spreadsheet.

My HTML is limiting the file types to `xls` and `xlsx`

```
<input type="file" id="filePicker" accept=".xls,.xlsx,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel"/>
```

But I want to truly validate that the file is actually an excel document, and validate that on the server.  I've been looking all over and cannot seem to find a solution that doesn't use the ASP.NET FileUpload Control.

This is my C# that I'm using to read the multipart form data and write the file to disk on the server.  This is where I'm hoping to do the validation.

```
[Route("ImportFile", Name = "ImportSPVFiles")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ImportFiles()
{
    if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
    {
        Stream data = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

        var parser = new MultipartFormDataParser(data);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];

        foreach (var file in parser.Files)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file.FileName))
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted");
            }
            string fileName = file.FileName;
            if (fileName.StartsWith("\"") && fileName.EndsWith("\""))
            {
                fileName = fileName.Trim('"');
            }
            if (fileName.Contains(@"/") || fileName.Contains(@"\"))
            {
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            }
            Stream fileData = file.Data;

            BufferedStream bStream = new BufferedStream(fileData);
            if(File.Exists(StoragePath + "\\" + file.FileName)){
                File.Delete(StoragePath + "\\" + file.FileName);
            }
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(StoragePath + "\\" + file.FileName)){
                bStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
           }

           fileQueue.Send(file.FileName);
       }

       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"Request was sent and being queued for processing");
       }
    else
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the server is there Excel installed so you can open this file in Excel and let Excel validate it for you?

Comment: @dee This is an part of an automated process, so opening the file in excel on the server wouldn't be viable.